# Magento order email not sent to customer

Tags: php, email, magento

I have a Magento 1.7.0.2 store and I have a problem regarding the order confirmation email sent to customers. Actually, the owner of the store receives the order confirmation but the customer doesn't

Could someone explain or give me a clue about what is happening?
I have to mention that the email confirmation isn't disabled nor the Email communication is disabled

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Which module are you using for e-mail ?

I would suggest https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension

Also, after installing this, grab PHPStorm editor and install xdebug package on the server, and then debug the whole stuff =)

Answer (score 1):

There could be many things preventing a customer from receiving an order confiromation email.

Make sure the server you are sending the email from (your Magento server) is setup with the correct [SPF records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework).  Many email providers will block emails coming from servers that are not authorized to send emails on the domain's behalf.

Also, check your servers email send logs.  The send logs will tell you what happened to the email (whether it was sent, bounced back, or rejected).  This is the best place to start for debugging email issues.

Lastly, you can try using a SMTP extension that allows Magento to send email using a valid SMTP login.  I personally use and recommend [SMTP Pro](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html).  This extension will also help you debug issues with your emails.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I am still confuse why the owner receives the email and the customer doesn't. So, I  guess that the mail server is correctly setup. Could you point me to the directory where the email log are written?

Comment: Is the owner email address using the **same domain** as the Magento website?  For example, `owner@magentosite.com` and Magento is located at `magentosite.com` also?  If that's the case, the reason the email works for the owner and not the customer is most likely because your emails are being flagged as spam on the customer's end (or they're being rejected).  You need to setup your SPF records to avoid this.  Also, your server log locations will vary depending on your host.  I'd recommend contacting your web-host if you're not sure where you can find the email logs.

Comment: I managed to get the logs, and indeed there are a lot of errors, like DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256: SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM: SIZE=13123